# How can I know the code for the colours I used in a ggplot to add a vertical line with this same colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Delay=rep(-5:6, times=8, each=1),
                 ID= rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times=1, each=24),
                 variable=rep(c("R2","SE"), times=4, each=12),
                 value=c(0.3,0.4,0.51,0.58,0.64,0.78,0.68,0.63,0.54,0.45,0.32,0.22,0.78,0.68,0.59,0.55,0.47,0.35,0.28,0.41,0.50,0.58,0.63,0.73,0.3,0.4,0.51,0.58,0.64,0.78,0.68,0.63,0.54,0.45,0.32,0.22,0.78,0.68,0.59,0.55,0.47,0.35,0.28,0.41,0.50,0.58,0.63,0.73,0.3,0.4,0.51,0.58,0.64,0.78,0.68,0.63,0.54,0.45,0.32,0.22,0.78,0.68,0.59,0.55,0.47,0.35,0.28,0.41,0.50,0.58,0.63,0.73,0.3,0.4,0.51,0.58,0.64,0.78,0.68,0.63,0.54,0.45,0.32,0.22,0.78,0.68,0.59,0.55,0.47,0.35,0.28,0.41,0.50,0.58,0.63,0.73))

df$ID <- as.factor(df$ID)
df$variable <- as.factor(df$variable)


Plot<-  ggplot(df[df$ID=="B",], aes(x=Delay, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_point(size=1) + 
  geom_line () +
  theme_hc() +
  theme(legend.position="right") +
  labs(x= '\nDelay',y=expression(R^{2})) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA))) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(-5,5,1)) + 
  scale_color_jco() 
Plot
```

I am plotting just data of `B`.

[image]

I would like to add a vertical for the minimum value of `SE` and a vertical line for the maximum value of `R2`. I would like that the lines had the same colour than the variable. However, I don't know how to do it. The colour of the vertical lines are black as you can see below, so I don't know how to indicate I want the specific colour I Used previously.

```
Plot <- Plot + geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
Plot
```

[image]

Does anyone know how add both vertical lines using the same colours that for the variables?

Comment: this might be a duplicate: generally, you can poke around in `ggplot_build(Plot)$data` to find the colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @r2evans approach to your specific problem is the correct one. However, to answer the more general question about how you can retrieve the colours from an applied colour scale (e.g. if you want to modify the colour etc), you can get it without going through `ggbuild`, using the following:

```
Plot$scales$get_scales("colour")$palette(2)
[1] "#0073C2FF" "#EFC000FF"
```

So we could do:

```
# Get colours
my_blue <- Plot$scales$get_scales("colour")$palette(2)[1]
my_yellow <- Plot$scales$get_scales("colour")$palette(2)[2]

# Get index of max R2 and min SE
maxR2 <- which.max(df$value[df$ID == "B" & df$variable == "R2"])
minSE <- which.min(df$value[df$ID == "B" & df$variable == "SE"])

# Get value of Delay at maxR2 and minSE
D_R2 <- df$Delay[df$ID == "B" & df$variable == "R2"][maxR2]
D_SE <- df$Delay[df$ID == "B" & df$variable == "SE"][minSE]

# Plot lines at the correct positions and with the desired colours
Plot + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = D_R2), colour = my_blue) +
       geom_vline(aes(xintercept = D_SE), colour = my_yellow)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron. As I have just commented to @r2evans, I modified a little bit the post. In the beginning, I summarized the post but now I think I shouldn't have done this. Now I have given my real case. I am using `theme_hc`, is that a problem? I like the colours it uses. On the other hand, as I now mention in the post, I have explained that what I want is to add a vertical line for the minimum value of `SE` and another for the maximum value of `R2`, using the same colours than for the variables. Is something of that a problem? I am still trying to figure out how to indicate this last

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* to find the color to instruct `ggplot2` to reuse it: you can supply "new data" with your desired x-intercept lines, and identify each v-line as belonging to a particular `variable` to use that variable's color.

I don't have your original `Plot` object or call, so my colors/theme will be different.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(Delay, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Delay, color = variable),
             data = data.frame(Delay = 0, variable = "R2"))
```

[image: single vertical line]

Or with multiple v-lines:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Delay, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Delay, color = variable),
             data = data.frame(Delay = c(-1, 1, 2), variable = c("R2", "SE", "R2")))
```

[image: multiple vertical lines]

---

This edit might answer this and your other question:

```r
mins <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df[,c("ID", "variable")], function(z) z[which.min(z$value),]))
mins
#    Delay ID variable value
# 12     6  A       R2  0.22
# 36     6  B       R2  0.22
# 60     6  C       R2  0.22
# 84     6  D       R2  0.22
# 19     1  A       SE  0.28
# 43     1  B       SE  0.28
# 67     1  C       SE  0.28
# 91     1  D       SE  0.28

ggplot(df[df$ID == "B",], aes(Delay, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Delay, color = variable), data = mins)
```

[image: more ggplot2]

Or if you want to see multiple `ID`s, you can facet,

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Delay, value, color = variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = Delay, color = variable), data = mins) +
  facet_wrap("ID")
```

[image: faceted ggplot2]

Comment: thanks for your time. I really appreciate it. I have updated my question because I summarized my question and it might have been a mistake. Now I shared the code for the plot and a complete dataframe to understand my situation. For the colours I used `theme_hc`, since it gives really nice colours. What I want is to just select one `ID` (in this example `B`), plot for this `ID` both `R2` and `SE`, and then, add a vertical line for the minimum value of `SE` and the maximum value of `R2`. And of course, I want both vertical lines to have the same colour than the variables.

Comment: Does something change from the previous situation? I mean, I am using `theme_hc` and I want to add the vertical lines for a minimum value of one factor level and another vertical line for the maximum value of the other factor level. I don't know If this makes your proposal invalid or not. Thanks against for your time

Comment: Your edits change nothing, have you tried to use this code? It seems like the problem you are asking for (in this comment) is how to find the min value (effectively from one of your other questions) and has nothing to do with how to find a color in `ggplot2` for a vertical line.

Comment: Thanks. I am not in front of my plot and I can check your proposal. I asked you just in case. Yes, I asked that in other question because it is a different topic. However, I was wondering if that could change the type of reply here. My other doubt was about using `theme_hc`. I will try your code later and I will tell you. Thanks again

Comment: Dekike, see my edit. The addition of the `mins` logic and object give you dynamic vertical lines from your data. If you vary your data a bit more, the `facet_wrap` will be a bit more informing, though faceting isn't required: whatever filtering you do to `df[df$ID == ...,]` should be done to `mins[mins$ID = ...,]` as well. Regardless, this works using whatever theme or color-scheme you want, so the fact that I don't have `ggthemes` installed should not change the fact that I believe this should work fine for you.

Comment: Dekike, you'd prefer to mess around with the grob internals of a plot in lieu of letting `ggplot2` manage it for you? I think doing it the `ggplot2`-way is more extensible, flexible, resilient, and perhaps compatible with extensions.